# Solving coupled ODES which varies with time in Python

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-integration

While trying to solve 6 couple equation using odeint it say
"p = odeint(odes,r0,θ0,ϕ0,x0,z0,t)
NameError: name 'r0' is not defined"

Code:
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import sin, cos, pi

```
def odes(p, t):
# constants
Ω=9.74e-3
B_θ=-8.6e-6*sin(θ)
B_r=25893.2e-9*cos(θ)
β=-9.36e-10
# assigning each ODE to a vector element
r = p[1]
θ = p[3]
ϕ = p[5]
x = p[2]
y = p[4]
z = p[6]

# defining the ODEs
drdt = x
dxdt = r*(y**2 + (z+Ω)**2 * sin(θ)**2 - β*z*sin(θ)*B_θ)
dθdt = y
dydt = (-2*x*y-r*(z+Ω)**2*sin(θ)*cos(θ)+β*r*z*sin(θ)*B_r)/r
dϕdt = z
dzdt = (-2*x*(z+Ω)*sin(θ)-2*r*y*(z+Ω)*cos(θ)+β*(x*B_θ-r*y*B_r))/(r*sin(θ))

return [drdt, dxdt, dθdt, dydt, dϕdt, dzdt]

# initial conditions
r0 = 0.71e+8
θ0 = 0.5*pi
ϕ0 = 0
x0 = 0
y0 = 0
z0 = 0

# time window
t = np.linspace(0,15,1000)
p = odeint(odes,r0,θ0,ϕ0,x0,z0,t)

r=p[:,1]
θ=p[:,3]
ϕ=p[:,5]
x=p[:,2]
y=p[:,4]
z=p[:,6]

# plot the results
plt.semilogy(t,r)
plt.semilogy(t,x)
plt.semilogy(t,θ)
plt.semilogy(t,y)
plt.semilogy(t,ϕ)
plt.semilogy(t,z)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple errors in your code that prevent it from running:

- The indentation is wrong. This could be a copy-paste error, but in python indentation is a syntax element.
- `θ` is used in "constants" before it is defined as "vector element" (or state component)
- python is zero-based, the array indices go from 0 to 5, not 1 to 6
- `odeint` only takes one initial state variable. In the vector case this has to be a tuple or array

Next the components have wildly different scales. This is of no import for a fixed-step solver, but can lead to distortions in a step-size controller, as some components get shadowed by the largest or fastest changing components. Scale the components individually, so that the solver sees only uniformly scaled components. With these changes I get to a plot, but that does not look realistic, the radius increases rapidly while the simulations are for a stable radius with small oscillations.

[image: plots of the components]

```
scales = np.array([1e7, 0.1, 1, 1e-20, 10, 0.1])

def odes(p, t):
    # assigning each ODE to a vector element
    r,x,θ,y,ϕ,z = p*scales
    # constants
    Ω=9.74e-3
    B_θ=-8.6e-6*sin(θ)
    B_r=25893.2e-9*cos(θ)
    β=-9.36e-10

    # defining the ODEs
    drdt = x
    dxdt = r*(y**2 + (z+Ω)**2 * sin(θ)**2 - β*z*sin(θ)*B_θ)
    dθdt = y
    dydt = (-2*x*y-r*(z+Ω)**2*sin(θ)*cos(θ)+β*r*z*sin(θ)*B_r)/r
    dϕdt = z
    dzdt = (-2*x*(z+Ω)*sin(θ)-2*r*y*(z+Ω)*cos(θ)+β*(x*B_θ-r*y*B_r))/(r*sin(θ))

    return np.array([drdt, dxdt, dθdt, dydt, dϕdt, dzdt])/scales

# initial conditions
r0 = 7.1e+07 
θ0 = 0.5*pi
ϕ0 = 0
x0 = 0
y0 = 0
z0 = 0

# time window
t = np.arange(0,100*60,10)
p0 = np.array([r0,x0,θ0,y0,ϕ0,z0])/scales
p = odeint(odes,p0,t, atol=1e-8, rtol=1e-10)

r,x,θ,y,ϕ,z = p.T*scales[:,None]

# plot the results
fig,ax=plt.subplots(2,3,figsize=(6,4))
for a,u in zip(ax.flatten(),[r,x,θ,y,ϕ,z]):
    a.plot(t,u); a.grid()

plt.tight_layout(); plt.show()
```

Comment: thank you so much for you thorough explanation. Yes the indentation changed while copying here. Apart from that, all that you have corrected are new knowledge to me. This was my first coding in life! With learned men like you ready to help learning becomes fun and meaningful. For the time being I shall now get back learning more and may be, one day I can also help others. Thank you Sir.

Comment: Sir, if If the values of B_r and B_θ  are replaced with,  B_θ = (R/r)**4*g_2*cos(θ)*sin(θ)
    B_r = 2*(R/r)**4*g_2*(0.5*(3*cos(θ)**2-1)) so that their values are calculated at each iterated values of r and θ what changes/addition should I made. R=60,260,000m g_2 = 5183 nT.